# How can I update existing .crt file with new encrypted rsa .key file?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Suppose I have 2 files: an RSA key file `client.key` and a certification file `client.crt`.

I have created them without pass-phrase and now I have encrypted `client.key` file with pass-phrase by command:

```
openssl rsa -des3 -in client.key -out client-enc.key
```

Now I want to re-create/update `client.crt` file with client-enc.key. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

A certificate contains a public key and signatures of this public key. This is not confidential information; sometimes you might not want to reveal it for privacy, but this isn't a common enough concern that there would be a specific certificate encryption format. If you want to encrypt the certificate, use your favorite encryption tool, e.g. PGP/GPG.

Is your concern that you've changed the key? If so, you're confused as to what the key and certificate represent, and since this is a rather important matter, I advise reading more on the topic.

- If you've only put a password on the key file, that's something you did to the *key file*, i.e. to the medium in which you stored the key. The encryption of the private key file is an independent operation, not directly related to the fact that the file contains a private key. But because protecting a private key for confidentiality is a very common requirement, there is a standard format and an `openssl` command for doing that. The key is the same, but this particular copy of the key now requires a password to be read.
- If you had actually changed the private key (which, from your description, you haven't!), you would have to regenerate the certificate from scratch. The fact that a public key only corresponds to one particular private key is fundamental in public-key cryptography: the public key represents *your* identity, and (knowledge of) the private key is the way you *prove* your identity.

Comment: I was look inside the .crt file as I see a block of "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" so I think it has embedded rsa key inside but seen I was wrong :P

Comment: @Uoc: It has a certificate, which contains a *public* RSA key.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need to.  The `.crt` file only contains the public half of the key, it does not contain a copy of the private key, and you haven't changed the content of the private key anyway — you've just wrapped it inside a symmetric encryption layer (decrypted by the passphrase).  Why do you believe you need to update the certificate?

Comment: Yes, I think so!

Comment: The certificate file contains the whole public key, not just a fingerprint of it! (Plus a signature that guarantees the authenticity, that's actually why it's called a certificate and you request it from a certification authority)